# Can I use "As presented in the report,..."?

Tags: sentence-structure

I'm writing an academic report and wondering if this sentence is ok:***As presented/discussed*** in Report No. 2, the Insured has fully complied with regulations on fire safety.

"As presented/discussed" in this context seems grammatically wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "As *stated* in Report No. 2"

Comment: Thanks, but what about "as discussed"?

Comment: Was there actually any discussion?

Comment: No. Actually, I want to refer to the meaning "stated" or "mentioned".

Answer (score 1):

Both of the words are correct in the sentence, but may sound a bit awkward depending on the context. Check out this list of **analytical verbs** that may help you - you will find that most of them can replace your chosen words (in past tense), but some will sound better than others:

[Analytical verbs](https://bhsenglishdepartment.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/analyticalverbs.pdf)

Comment: The link here has gone dead.